# Finding the maximum of the entries of matrix $A B^T$ without computing $A B^T$

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Given tall matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, where $n \gg k$, let $C := AB^T$. I want to calculate $$ \max C = \max AB^T$$ where $\max: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ returns the maximal entry in a matrix. Is there a way to calculate the max element without explicitly calculating $C$? This is beneficial in case $n$ is large.

---

#### Background

This problem arises when solving LASSO for large scale data. Basically you choose an active set (i.e., parameters that are not zero and then you set the others to zero) which is relatively small to the number of parameters you want to optimize over. You optimize over the active set using whatever algorithm and then you check the optimality condition for the zero coefficients, which is defined as the maximal element in the multiplication of the residual matrix with the data matrix is less than the regularization parameter. Multiplication the residual (i.e., $A$) with the data (i.e., $B$) is the computational bottleneck.

Comment: If both matrices have a row which dominates all other rows (i.e. the greatest element for a column lies on that row for each column), then this can be done trivially. For the general case, not so sure.

Comment: I believe the standard technique here is to use locality-sensitive hashing and then only compute the inner products of the rows of A and B that end up in a lot of the same buckets. With that said, Ballard et. al. propose a technique called _diamond sampling_ in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03872.pdf) paper that seems promising. I'm not well-versed enough in this area to give a good canonical answer, but hopefully this helps